# JQuery height of dropdown box values not adjusting after filtering

Tags: jquery, filter, height, dropdown

I have two dropdown boxes, one with something like "City" (list of all the cities), and the other one with the list of stores like "Stores | City" with around 3000 values.

By default (nothing selected):

[Cities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y1VY.png)

And also by default (with nothing selected):

[Stores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTRnA.png)

I'm filtering (only showing) the values of the dropdown box of the stores with the selection of the value of the Cities list and it's working properly with the results, but the only problem is when I have only few stores as a result of the filter the dropdow appears collapsed like this:

[4 Stores filtered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW8Qv.png)

If the resukt of the filter have few results is appearing like that. Can I increase the appearance of the result values?

Here's the code:

```
    //function to show Farmácia Filtered by Concelho (default são todas)
var showCity = function(selectedState){     
 $('#field_14292 option').hide();
    $('#field_14292').find('option').filter(function(){
        var city = $(this).text();

    var str1 = " | ";
    var res = str1.concat(selectedState);

    // Only shows on the dropdown of Farmácia only values that end on " | selectedState" (ex.: " | Lisboa"), it's case sensative    
    return city.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(res.toLowerCase())!=-1;         

    }).show();

    //set default value for dropdown Farmácia
    var defaultCity = $('#field_14292 option:visible:first').text();
    $('#field_14292').val(defaultCity);

};

//set default state for Concelho
var state = $('#field_3320').val();
showCity(state);

//on change Concelho event call showCity function (filter campo Farmácia) 
$('#field_3320').change(function(){
   showCity($(this).val());
});
```

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I found out what the issue was.

Since I was hiding the selection options (but they were still there it mess it up representing the dropdown box list).

The trick is to remove them when they're are not to be shown instead of hiding, and adding them when nothing is to be filtered.